# What could be the possible reasons if nslookup command for a domain is not showing correct records?

Tags: azure, networking, nslookup, godaddy-api

I am not able to access one of my website from office which is hosted in Microsoft azure. When i have tried to lookup for dns lookup.
I is not showing me the correct ip address or showing some thing like mydomainname.kkph.com.

While i can access the same website from other devices around the world.

I have also checked with Godaddy support team but didn't find any issue at their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could ensure that you have a correct IP address binds with your website and have a mapping `A` or `CNAME` record in your DNS domain provider.

For this issue, you could check the followings:

- DNS cache on the local office machine. Use `ipconfig/flushdns` to clear it.
- DNS Suffix Search List. You could check if you have a DNS suffix automatically appended to your hostname when you query. You could check it via 'ipconfig/all' or find the box **Append parent suffixes of the primary DNS suffix**  and **DNS Suffix Search List** under the `Advanced TCP/IP Settings`---`DNS`. Also, to avoid using the search list, always use a Fully Qualified Domain Name (that is, add the trailing dot to the name) when you run `nslookup fqdn`. Read [here](https://www.activexperts.com/support/network-monitor/nslookup/).
- Try to `nslookup` on another machine from the office to find if there is something wrong with a specific machine.

If no luck, please show the result of `nslookup` for further help. I would like to suggest to capture the netmon traces on your local environment.

Comment: Thanks Nancy, I had also tried the ipconfig /flushdns but even executing this command we were getting the same result.

Comment: Do you try another machine from your office? Do you nslookup fqdn?

Comment: Hi Nancy, here you can see the results, i have just  masked domain name. [Result in CMD](https://ibb.co/K55B9DQ)

Comment: It seems that your company is using [opendns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS) as the local DNS proxy server, you could check if OpenDNS could resolve the domain name(beta.com) or configure it with a DNS zone well in that server.